# Getting empty list when accessing element and tag in xml file using ElementTree

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing, elementtree

The idea is to get the value of tag `endTime` for the following `xml`:

```html
<epochs xmlns="http://www.egi.com/epochs_mff" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <epoch>
    <beginTime>0</beginTime>
    <endTime>3586221000</endTime>
    <firstBlock>1</firstBlock>
    <lastBlock>897</lastBlock>
  </epoch>
  <epoch>
    <beginTime>3750143000</beginTime>
    <endTime>5549485000</endTime>
    <firstBlock>898</firstBlock>
    <lastBlock>1347</lastBlock>
  </epoch>
</epochs>
```

Yet, accessing the tag directly return an empty list:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(r'epochs.xml')
epoch_list=tree.findall("epoch")
```

However, looping through the `tree` does return the `endTime` value.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(r'epochs.xml')

for elem in tree:
    for subelem in elem:
        print(subelem.text)
```

May I know how can I retrieve directly the `endTime` with the value of **300937000**?

Comment: Check your second code block. The third line doesn't seem to be complete

Comment: Dirty work around is to [Parse XML Files Using Python’s BeautifulSoup](https://linuxhint.com/parse_xml_python_beautifulsoup/) using the line `result = soup_page.find_all("endtime")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code failed is that your XML uses a default namespace
(*xmlns="http://..."*).

But your call to *findall* contains *epoch* **without** any namespace, so it is not
likely to find anything.

To process **namespaced** XML, you have to:

- create a dictionary of used namespaces (*{prefix: namespace}*),
- include the prefix of the relevant namespace in the XPath expression,
- pass the above dictionary as the second argument of *findall*.

Something like:

```
ns = {'ep': 'http://www.egi.com/epochs_mff'}
epoch_list = tree.findall('ep:epoch', ns)
```

Then the result is:

```
[<Element '{http://www.egi.com/epochs_mff}epoch' at 0x...>]
```

And to get the content your *endTime* element, if you don't care about
any intermediate elements in the XML tree, run:

```
tree.findtext('.//ep:endTime', namespaces=ns)
```

Other choice is to pass full XML path, starting from the content of
the root element, but remember about the namespace prefix at each step:

```
tree.findtext('ep:epoch/ep:endTime', namespaces=ns)
```

If you have **multiple** *endTime* elements, one of possible solutions
is to process them in a loop.

This time *findtext* is useless as it finds only the first matching element.
You should use a loop based on *findall* and then (within the loop)
retrieve the text of the current element and make the intended use of it,
e.g.:

```
for it in tree.findall('ep:epoch/ep:endTime', namespaces=ns):
    print(it.text)
```

Of course, replace *print* with whatever you need to consume the
text found.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation @Valdi_Bo. Just to extend the discussion further. How to loop the `tree.findtext('ep:epoch/ep:endTime', namespaces=ns)` if there exist more than two `endTime` instances?